# Enabling VBA project through the Excel Document

Tags: excel, vba

I have finally got all the code working. Thanks to all for some many awesome links. Now one last hurdle.

I am sending this file to multiple stations. Not all the PC's will have Office on them, just might have Excel Viewer. I have made a note in the sheet to explaine they need to run this on a Back Office machine with Office.

So the issue I am having is that when they click on the Email Button or the other Buttons I am getting an error "1004 Programmatic access to the Visual Basics. Project is not trusted."

So I know that I can ask the end users to go through Settings/Macro Section and enable access to VBA Project.

Is this a way to code that into the sheet so when they open the file it just enables the option? Or Can I add yet another Button to Enable it? Below is the VB SCript.

Thanks

Chris

```
Private Sub EmailWorkbook_Click()

'This subroutine uses ...
'Public Function EmailThisWorkbook(Optional ByVal TO_Recipients As String = "", Optional ByVal CC_Recipients As String = "", Optional ByVal BCC_Recipients As String = "", Optional ByVal Message_SUBJECT As String = "", Optional ByVal Message_BODY As String = "", Optional ByVal FROM_Sender As String = "")

On Error Resume Next

Dim StationCode As String
    StationCode = Left(Environ$("computername"), 3)
    'Grabs the first 3 characters, starting from left side, of the environmental variable 'computername' where the email is being sent from

Dim SendTO As String
    SendTO = "me@somwhere.net"
    'or use... SendTO = "" ... to prompt user for an email address

Dim BSOSubject As String
    BSOSubject = "BSO Scanner Inventory Report for " & StationCode

Dim BSOBody As String
    BSOBody = "BSO Scanner Inventory Report for " & StationCode

Message_Result = ThisWorkbook.EmailThisWorkbook(SendTO, "", "", BSOSubject, BSOBody, "")

If Message_Result = -2 Then
    MsgBox "The Send function is disabled while workbook contains unsaved changes."
End If

If Message_Result = -1 Then
    MsgBox "Email Cancelled"
End If

If Message_Results = 1 Then
    MsgBox "Email Sent Succesfully"
End If

If Message_Result = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Email Failed To Send"
End If

End Sub
```

Next subroutine:

```
Private Sub AddDevice_Click()
Dim TargetWorkSheet_Wks As Worksheet
    Set TargetWorkSheet_Wks = ActiveSheet
    TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Unprotect ("chris")

Dim Button_GUI_Obj As OLEObject

Dim InsertionRow_Str As String
    InsertionRow_Str = "C" & TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range("B25").Value

Dim NewRowNumber_Int
    NewRowNumber_Int = TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(-1).Value + 1

Dim NewButtonID_Str As String

TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).EntireRow.RowHeight = 30

'Column -1
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, -1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, -1).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, -1).WrapText = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, -1).Borders.Weight = xlThick
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, -1).Font.Name = "Calibri"
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, -1).Font.Size = 18
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, -1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, -1).Font.Bold = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, -1).Font.Italic = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, -1).Font.Underline = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, -1).Font.Strikethrough = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, -1).Font.Subscript = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, -1).Font.Superscript = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, -1) = ""
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, -1).Locked = True

TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 0).WrapText = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 54, 52)
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 0).Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 0).Font.Name = "Calibri"
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 0).Font.Size = 18
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 0).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 0).Font.Bold = True
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 0).Font.Italic = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 0).Font.Underline = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 0).Font.Strikethrough = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 0).Font.Subscript = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 0).Font.Superscript = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 0) = NewRowNumber_Int
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 0).Locked = True

TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 1).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 1).WrapText = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 52)
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 1).Borders.Weight = xlThick
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 1).Font.Name = "Calibri"
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 1).Font.Size = 18
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 1).Font.Bold = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 1).Font.Italic = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 1).Font.Underline = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 1).Font.Strikethrough = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 1).Font.Subscript = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 1).Font.Superscript = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 1) = TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range("D18").Value
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 1).Locked = True

TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 2).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 2).WrapText = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 51, 0)
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 2).Borders.Weight = xlThick
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 2).Font.Name = "Calibri"
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 2).Font.Size = 18
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 2).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 2).Font.Bold = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 2).Font.Italic = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 2).Font.Underline = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 2).Font.Strikethrough = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 2).Font.Subscript = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 2).Font.Superscript = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 2) = TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range("E18").Value
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 2).Locked = True

TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 3).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 3).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 3).WrapText = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 3).Borders.Weight = xlThick
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 3).Font.Name = "Calibri"
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 3).Font.Size = 18
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 3).Font.Bold = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 3).Font.Italic = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 3).Font.Underline = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 3).Font.Strikethrough = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 3).Font.Subscript = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 3).Font.Superscript = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 3) = TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range("F18").Value
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 3).Locked = True

TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 4).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 4).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 4).WrapText = True
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 230, 230)
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 4).Borders.Weight = xlThick
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 4).Font.Name = "Calibri"
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 4).Font.Size = 10
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 4).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 4).Font.Bold = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 4).Font.Italic = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 4).Font.Underline = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 4).Font.Strikethrough = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 4).Font.Subscript = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 4).Font.Superscript = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 4) = TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range("G18").Value
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 4).Locked = True

TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 5).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 5).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 5).WrapText = True
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 230, 230)
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 5).Borders.Weight = xlThick
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 5).Font.Name = "Calibri"
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 5).Font.Size = 10
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 5).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 5).Font.Bold = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 5).Font.Italic = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 5).Font.Underline = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 5).Font.Strikethrough = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 5).Font.Subscript = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 5).Font.Superscript = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 5) = TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range("H18").Value
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 5).Locked = True

NewButtonID_Str = Year(Now()) & Month(Now()) & Day(Now()) & Hour(Now()) & Minute(Now()) & Second(Now())
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 6).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 6).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 6).WrapText = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 6).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 54, 52)
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 6).Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 6).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThick
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 6).Font.Name = "Calibri"
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 6).Font.Size = 18
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 6).Font.Color = RGB(150, 54, 52)
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 6).Font.Bold = True
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 6).Font.Italic = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 6).Font.Underline = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 6).Font.Strikethrough = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 6).Font.Subscript = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 6).Font.Superscript = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 6) = NewButtonID_Str
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 6).Locked = True

Call Add_CommandButton(1, "Save_" & NewButtonID_Str, "Save", InsertionRow_Str, 30, 23.25, 20, 3, "SaveOrUndoDevice")
    Set Button_GUI_Obj = TargetWorkSheet_Wks.OLEObjects("Save_" & NewButtonID_Str)
        Button_GUI_Obj.Visible = False

Call Add_CommandButton(1, "Undo_" & NewButtonID_Str, "Undo", InsertionRow_Str, 33, 23.25, 51, 3, "SaveOrUndoDevice")
    Set Button_GUI_Obj = TargetWorkSheet_Wks.OLEObjects("Undo_" & NewButtonID_Str)
        Button_GUI_Obj.Visible = False
Call Add_CommandButton(1, "Edit_" & NewButtonID_Str, "Edit", InsertionRow_Str, 30, 23.25, 20, 3, "EditDevice")

Call Add_CommandButton(1, "Up_" & NewButtonID_Str, "U", InsertionRow_Str, 18, 23.25, 51, 3, "MoveDevice")
Call Add_CommandButton(1, "Down_" & NewButtonID_Str, "D", InsertionRow_Str, 15, 23.25, 70, 3, "MoveDevice")
    If TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(-1, 0).Value = 0 Then
        Set Button_GUI_Obj = TargetWorkSheet_Wks.OLEObjects("Up_" & NewButtonID_Str)
            Button_GUI_Obj.Enabled = False
    End If
    If TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(1, 0).Value = "x" Then
        Set Button_GUI_Obj = TargetWorkSheet_Wks.OLEObjects("Down_" & NewButtonID_Str)
            Button_GUI_Obj.Enabled = False
    End If
    If NewRowNumber_Int > 1 Then
        PreviousRecord = TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(-1, 6).Value
        Set Button_GUI_Obj = TargetWorkSheet_Wks.OLEObjects("Down_" & PreviousRecord)
            Button_GUI_Obj.Enabled = True
    End If

Call Add_CommandButton(1, "Delete_" & NewButtonID_Str, "X", InsertionRow_Str, 15, 23.25, 85, 3, "RemoveDevice")


TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 7).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 7).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 7).WrapText = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 7).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 7).Borders.Weight = xlThick
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 7).Font.Name = "Calibri"
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 7).Font.Size = 18
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 7).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 7).Font.Bold = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 7).Font.Italic = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 7).Font.Underline = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 7).Font.Strikethrough = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 7).Font.Subscript = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 7).Font.Superscript = False
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 7) = ""
TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, 7).Locked = True

TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range("B25") = TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range("B25").Value + 1

TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Protect ("chris")

End Sub
```

Comment: You have an enormous amount of duplication. For example, you could use a simple loop to set the properties of everything. Like  `For j = -1 to 7 Step 1`  then use `(0, j)` in your Offset, then `Next j` to loop. Then you just have 1 formatting section to deal with. I realize each section contains a line or two that's different, but for the rest of the formatting it's the same. It would make it a lot easier to read and keep track of.

Comment: `so when they open the file it just enables the option?` - If Microsoft allowed for VBA to be able enable VBA security would get blown out of the window :) You must tell users to change settings for it to work.

Comment: I concur with @Mitch, you have 11 lines for each cell that are identical. I have two recommendations: [1] Resize the range and apply the 11 identical lines, i.e. `TargetWorkSheet_Wks.Range(InsertionRow_Str).Offset(0, -1).Resize(, 9).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter` and so on. [2] Learn to use `With`, i.e. `With TargetWorkSheet_Wks` ... `With .Range(InsertionRow_Str)` ... `With .Offset(0, -1)` ... `.Value = ""` ... `End With` ... `End With` ... `End With` (this makes things easier to manage if you change variable names and also improves performance).

Comment: One more thing, you have some sort of method called `Add_CommandButton` - if it's a Sub, convert it to a Function and within that Function return a reference to the created button itself, so then you can do `Set Button_GUI_Obj = Add_CommandButton(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

VBA can't turn off VBA security, to help prevent [macro viruses](https://web.archive.org/web/20060325224147/http://www3.ca.com/securityadvisor/newsinfo/collateral.aspx?cid=33338).  It's a good thing that software can't readily disable virus scanners.  However, there may be other solutions.  (Technically you *can* change the registry with VBA, except that changes don't take effect until you restart Excel, and restarting Excel will reset the security-related settings.)

---

Are these users all on the same network?  Part of the same workgroup?  If so, you could enable macros using the Group Policy Editor like [this](http://techgenix.com/aquicktiptoconfiguregrouppolicysettingsinworkgroupsecuritymodel/) or similar options [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954395.aspx).

---

You could set the folder where your Excel file is located as a [Trusted Location](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4).

---

You could send the users a `.REG` file to update the registry that enables macro trust.  This key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\_{version}_\Excel\Security\VBAWarnings
```

can be set to:

> 1 = Enable all macros *(not recommended)*
>   2 = Disable all with notification
>   3 = Disable all except digitally signed macros
>   4 = Disable all without notification

More info [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/03234330-9e23-4922-9cee-9359ff08302d/registry-setting-for-changing-macro-security-to-enable-all-macros?forum=officesetupdeployprevious) or [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cristib/2012/02/29/vba-how-to-programmatically-enable-access-to-the-vba-object-model-using-macros/).

**For example**, if the user is running Excel 16 on Windows 2000+ you could create a file called `EnableMacros.reg` like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security]
"VBAWarnings"=dword:1
```

...and distribute it to your users with instructions to execute it before opening Excel.  They will get a warning that "Windows could stop working properly", although that can be avoided by opening the `.REG` file *silently*, perhaps with a command in a batch file:

```
regedit.exe /s enablemacros.reg
```

...although if the user's [registry permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) are restricted (and also can't run `regedit.exe` with [elevated privileges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742497(v=vs.85).aspx)), then the change might not take effect.

### Disclaimers:

1. Messing with the registry can break things.
2. Defeating security defaults might be a bad idea.

Comment: Yes most of the machines are pretty locked down via Group Policies. As an Admin I can make the changes myself. So if there is a way to use a VB script to make the changes to the Registry using my credentials then would that work? Most of the people receiving this file are not very computer literate so having them do anything like you suggested would be going over the top, plus they wont have access anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the code change.....Will make things easier. So eventually I am going to want to make this Excel sheet actually update a master DB. Would you recommend Access or just keep it in Excel? The type of info is going to be limited, Serial Numbers, Station Codes, Active or Inactive. We are End of life on current hardware. Once new ones come in I will be entering the info into the Excel sheet to update the master DB. Scanners fixed, sent to Stations, will need to be updated in the master DB.

Comment: If it not a huge amount of data, then I would say keep it in Excel.  On the other hand, a reasonably-sized existing project like this is a great way to get started in Access & VBA.   (Btw you might want to edit your question to change the email addresses if they are real or they risk being forever crawled & spammed!)

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I will make the changes. I think going to Access is the right way to go. I will give me something else to learn. Thanks again for the information and thanks to EVERYONE for giving me the guidance to get this working.